# Outputting a Seaborn heatmap chart of a pandas DataFrame using Bokeh

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a Seaborn heatmap chart and output it using Bokeh.

Here's how I plot the chart:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import seaborn as sns
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame([['item1',1,2,3,4,'SEPT'],
   ...:                    ['item2',5,6,7,8,'OCT'],
   ...:                    ['item3',9,10,11,12,'SEPT'],
   ...:                    ['item1',13,14,15,16,'OCT'],
   ...:                    ['item2',17,18,19,20,'SEPT'],
   ...:                    ['item3',21,22,23,24,'OCT']],
   ...:                    columns = ['itemName','metric1',
   ...:                    'metric2','metric3','metric4','Month'])
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
  itemName  metric1  metric2  metric3  metric4 Month
0    item1        1        2        3        4  SEPT
1    item2        5        6        7        8   OCT
2    item3        9       10       11       12  SEPT
3    item1       13       14       15       16   OCT
4    item2       17       18       19       20  SEPT
5    item3       21       22       23       24   OCT

In [2]: df1 = df.pivot(index='itemName',columns='Month',values='metric1')
   ...: 
   ...: df1
Out[2]: 
Month     OCT  SEPT
itemName           
item1      13     1
item2       5    17
item3      21     9

In [3]: sns.heatmap(df1, annot=True)
Out[3]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2a3836cc2b0>
```

[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFeGl.png)

So far, so good. Then I attempt to output the chart with Bokeh, using an [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.3/examples/compat/seaborn_tsplot.py) as the base:

```
In [4]: from bokeh import mpl
   ...: from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show

In [5]: output_file("seaborn_heatmap.html", title="seaborn heatmap example")

In [6]: show(mpl.to_bokeh())
WARNING:C:\Users\<Username>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\validation\check.py:W-1001 (NO_DATA_RENDERERS): Plot has no data renderers: Plot, ViewModel:Plot, ref _id: b78fd176-bffd-4fd0-9b7c-a169d299f541
```

This results in an empty chart. What have I done wrong?

P.S. The reason for using Bokeh is I want to switch between different sources of values for the heatmap on the fly using a dropdown or something similar. However, I'm not too deeply invested in any of the libraries used, so if you can suggest a free alternative that will do interactive heatmaps more easily, I will gladly look into it.

Comment: MPL compat for Bokeh relies on a third part library that is incomplete and no longer maintained, unfortunately. Any current capability there is provided "as-is" just in case it is useful. I'd suggest just using native Bokeh APIs directly if you really want to take advantage of Bokeh's interactive capabilities anyway. There are some examples of heatmaps using `bokeh.plotting` API: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html and http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/les_mis.html

Comment: I figured that was the case, but was hoping I was just missing something. Thanks for the advice, and I guess this is as close to an answer as it gets, though I don't believe I can accept a comment.

Comment: This is no longer possible. Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), and `mpl.to_bokeh()` has been removed. Also see [this Github comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6249#issuecomment-299981362) by bryevdv

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not supported and does not exist. There is no feature or function, in either Bokeh or Matplotlib, that will convert Matplotlib output to Bokeh output.  Therefore, the answer to this question is:

> What you are asking for is not possible.

*(Speaking as the co-creator and lead maintainer of Bokeh for 5+ years) It is important for users to clearly and unambiguously understand that there is no "magic bullet" to convert MPL to Bokeh. Anything else is **misinformation***.

The only option for generating Bokeh output is to use native Bokeh APIs directly, e.g. the [`bokeh.plotting`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html) API.